# Different behavior for edit(data)/vi(data) in RStudio on OS X

Tags: r, macos, editor, rstudio

I have RStudio on an OS X box, and have just reinstalled X11 to fix some of the reported problems with Yosemite breaking symlinks. I go forth to the prompt and enter:

```
> edit(iris[[5]])
```

and yield a new window with a wonderful

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", 
"virginica"), class = "factor")
```

and, refreshingly, I get the same result with

```
> vi(iris[[5]])
```

However, moving on to

```
data <- read.table(text="160525.000,38.63
160526.086,38.63
160526.604,38.62
160526.710,38.63
160526.343,38.62", sep=",")
date = "20150824"
data$Dates <- ymd_hms(paste(date,data$V1))
```

and attempting

```
> edit(data)
```

I am returned

```
> edit(data)
Error in edit.data.frame(data) : 
  can only handle vector and factor elements
```

yet

```
> vi(data)

structure(list(V1 = c(160525, 160526.086, 160526.604, 160526.71, 
160526.343), V2 = c(38.63, 38.63, 38.62, 38.63, 38.62), Dates = structure(c(1440432325, 
1440432326.086, 1440432326.604, 1440432326.71, 1440432326.343
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "Dates"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

in its own, separate, happy window.

Why would `edit` and `vi`, in RStudio, both invoking the same document editor -

> On the OS X GUI the argument [Editor] is ignored and the document editor is always used.

behave differently?

I am not (to the best of my knowledge) invoking `vi` with my call to `vi`, but rather the same editor as `edit`. Why would there be a difference in response to the input?

In case anyone thinks it relevant -

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.1                         
year           2015                        
month          06                          
day            18                          
svn rev        68531                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
nickname       World-Famous Astronaut
```